# What is the difference between displayName and commonName in LDAP?

Tags: ldap

In LDAP, the displayName and commonName fields appear to me to store the same thing, i.e. a user's full name. Can anyone explain what the intended difference is between them? When would you want them to be different?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following comment from [INetOrgPerson schema](http://www.openldap.org/devel//cvsweb.cgi/~checkout~/servers/slapd/schema/inetorgperson.schema?rev=1.4&hideattic=1&sortbydate=0) from OpenLDAP provides a simple explanation:

```
# displayName
# When displaying an entry, especially within a one-line summary list, it
# is useful to be able to identify a name to be used.  Since other attri-
# bute types such as 'cn' are multivalued, an additional attribute type is
# needed.  Display name is defined for this purpose.
```

Hope it helps :)